# Gallery picking images for some devices, but not picking images from other device

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a usecase where we just need to select images from the gallery. now the problem is that the emulators and some phone (such as Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 pro) are working fine. The gallery opens, user selects images and the images are received. But when doing this for OnePlus 8 and some Samsung devices, the gallery opens, the user selects the images but they are not being received on the Fragment.

I am opening the gallery like this :

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestStoragePermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        } else {
            val intent =
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
```

And receiving the image from the intent like:

```
    private var resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (result.data?.clipData != null) {
                    val count: Int = result.data!!.clipData
                        ?.itemCount
                        ?: 0
                    for (i in 0 until count) {
                        //Processing data here 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `we just need to select images from the gallery` You mean you as a programme you use ACTION_PICK. We are programmers too so tell straight away that you use ACTION_PICK to let the user select images from device. There is no 'Gallery' on an Android device. Only Gallery apps.

Comment: You do not need any permission to use ACTION_PICK so please remove that code.

Comment: `And receiving the image from the intent like:` You mean: And receiving the image from the ACTION_PICK intent like:

Comment: HI @blackapps the thing is that after receiving the image from any one of the gallery apps, I need to send the file in a multipart request so I do need the permission otherwise we get a crash when the multipart request is hit.

Comment: You need no permissions. And you did not edit your post with the remarks you got. Sigh..